# Filling form of remote site with cURL

Tags: php, curl

I am just trying to insert the data in a service using a form but whenever I run this on local host, it just gives me no output. 
Here is the code i used for just inserting my desired login details in putlocker site:

```
<?php


$url="http://www.putlocker.com/authenticate.php?login";

$postdata = "user=somthing&pass=something";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$result = curl_exec ($ch);
echo $result;  




?>
```

I hope somebody could take out some time and give some suggestions to solve this :)

Comment: DO NOT fill forms of remote sites with cURL. Fill them by hand. Forms are for humans.

Comment: Ohh wow thnx alot for the info mate i never knew it. PLease if u cant help atleast dont post such comments bro. Am just trying to learn nothing else.

Comment: And without such comments you'll never learn...

Comment: You could learn something legal instead.

Comment: What am i doing illegal here ?? I have my own premium acc. And i jus wanna knw how can i use cURL to insert values in there. Nothing illegal is intended just trying to learn from around thats all.And i dont want to login in the site. Just INSERT the values.

Answer (score -1):

A few tips :

- You should be using the URL the form is posted to (= action attribute of the form tag). I don't know if it's the one you used, which look like the URL of the form.
- I think you should use a `&` to separate your postdata : `$postdata = "user=somthing$pass=something";` should become in my opinion `$postdata = "user=somthing&pass=something";`
- if the login somehow has anything to do with cookies, I think it would need to be tested as I'm not a cUrl user and my PhP is rusty
- it may be the destination you're trying to send posts to is filtering requests to allow login only from the form, in that case you would be stuck.

Comment: Sir there is no form tag in the putlocker login page. And i rectified the '&' thing as you said but still no gain.And the other thing is am not trying to get in the site. Am jus trying to insert the login values in the username and password field :) But thanks alot for answering in a positive manner and not like the dude above ya. :)

Comment: Ok mods please close this thread. My problem solved. Now am easily able to fillup the form and login in putlocker :) And Bartdude i cannot +1 your answer as i dont have some reputation :)